# How to animate the number of vertices / splits of an object?

Tags: animation, subdivision-surface

I want to animate a plane from the topview.
It starts simple and flat but I want the number of splits / vertices to increase during the animation, so that it becomes some kind of low poly area with highs and lows.

Is there a possibility to animate the number of cuts / subdivisions / splits of an object?
To put it in another way: I want the plane to become more complex over time.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can modify the number of polygons during an animation. you can animate the shape of an object. Is there an animation reference you have in mind?

Comment: you can change the subdivision factor of the Subdivision Surface modifier, but you need to tell a bit more about your final purpose

Comment: ..depending on the exact effect you are looking to achieve, the _Remesh_,_Triangulate_, _Weld_, _Build_,_Decimate_  modifiers are also all animatable